# Calculate maximum averages in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, max, average

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZiz1.png)I have a table in SQL Server that contains two columns, one is a datetime and the other is the measurement that some sensors get for the datetime.

What I want to achieve is: the maximum of the hourly average per day. (The average per hour is made during a day, and the maximum of those hours is taken).

The maximum of the moving average (8hr) per day. (The average of 00:00am-08:00am, the average of 08:00am-04:00pm and the average of 04:00pm-00:00am, and the maximum of those three averages is taken).

This is the code I have so far, I think I calculate the moving average every 8 hours, but I don't know how to calculate the maximum of the averages.

Can someone help me?  Thanks in advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_specsO3_select]
    @Date1 date,
    @Date2 date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        snt.Time,
        CONVERT(DATE, snt.Time) AS DiaMesAnyo,
        sntu.Descripcion,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(snt.Time AS DATE), snt.Time) / 8 AS DivideDia,
        AVG(snt.Medida) AS Media
    FROM 
        [SDCTUEst].[dbo].[SensoresNoTrafico] AS snt
    INNER JOIN 
        [SDCTUEst].[dbo].[SensoresNoTraficoUnidades] AS sntu ON snt.ID = sntu.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[TipoSensoresAmbientales] AS tsa ON sntu.TipoEntradaSalida = tsa.Id
    WHERE 
        (snt.Time >= @Date1 AND snt.Time <= @Date2)
    GROUP BY 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(snt.Time AS DATE), snt.Time) / 8, snt.Time, snt.ID, sntu.Descripcion
END
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the desired output.

Comment: I have attached an image that I hope will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to calculate the maximum value of `AVG(snt.Medida)`. If so you can use `order by`. `Order by` mostly working after all commands. `Order by Media DESC` command firstly will be calculated AVG, after then will sort descending. The first record of the resulting data is the maximum value of the `Media` field. If you need only maximum value then use the TOP 1 on select for best performance. For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_specsO3_select]
    @Date1 date,
    @Date2 date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1  
        snt.Time,
        CONVERT(DATE, snt.Time) AS DiaMesAnyo,
        sntu.Descripcion,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(snt.Time AS DATE), snt.Time) / 8 AS DivideDia,
        AVG(snt.Medida) AS Media
    FROM 
        [SDCTUEst].[dbo].[SensoresNoTrafico] AS snt
    INNER JOIN 
        [SDCTUEst].[dbo].[SensoresNoTraficoUnidades] AS sntu ON snt.ID = sntu.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[TipoSensoresAmbientales] AS tsa ON sntu.TipoEntradaSalida = tsa.Id
    WHERE 
        (snt.Time >= @Date1 AND snt.Time <= @Date2)
    GROUP BY 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(snt.Time AS DATE), snt.Time) / 8, snt.Time, snt.ID, sntu.Descripcion
    ORDER BY Media DESC 
END
```

Comment: It is a good option but I need the maximum of each day, TOP 1 only returns the maximum of all.